# What is the fastest way to query for NULL values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find all records which contain NULLs in a column. The column is indexed. However, when when I set my `where` clause to

```
where person_key is null
```

SQL Server takes a really long time to respond. Queries looking for specific values, on the other hand, return quite quickly.

Is there a way to write the query to speed up the the search for records with  NULLs in person_key?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question. We need to see the table's DDL, the index definitions, the full query, and the actual execution plan.

Comment: So, are there no general rules to follow when querying for NULLs in an indexed column? The query is pretty much select * from vw_gld_re_gift where person_key is NULL

Comment: How long does it take to get the rows where person_key is not null? Maybe the performance issue is not what you think it is.

Comment: @SeanLange I get no response after 30 minutes and kill the query. When looking for records with a particular person_key, response time is < 5 seconds

Comment: Define what you mean by "takes a really long time to respond" - long time to return all rows, long time to return first row?

Comment: You can try putting a filtered index with person_key IS NULL and see if you get a speed boost.

Comment: It `person_key` is indexed, and you have very small percentage of nulls, it is likely that the server will go with index seek followed by cluster index lookup to satisfy the `select *`. If there is significant number of nulls, then, given the `select *`, it is very likely that the server will ignore the index altogether and scan the table, as it has to do that anyway to satisfy the `*`. As a starting point, try querying only columns included in the index on `person_key`.

Comment: Please post the whole query. Search by key should be in milliseconds.

Comment: < 5 seconds is a red flag for me finding a specific row. It should be nearly instant. This looks like it might be a view? Maybe the real issue is that the view needs some help? Without table definitions and such this is just guesswork.

Comment: "Both columns are indexed" -- What does this even mean? Which two columns?

Comment: Try doing: {select person_key, count(*) from table group by person_key order by person_key} and see if that comes back fast and you will see how many nulls there are.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find all records which contain NULLs in a column. The
>   column is indexed. However, when when I set my where clause to
>
> ```
> where person_key is null
> ```
>
> SQL Server takes a really long time to respond. Queries looking for
>   specific values, on the other hand, return quite quickly.
>
> Is there a way to write the query to speed up the the search for
>   records with NULLs in person_key? Thanks!

Like everyone has commented above, to provide proper advice, a little bit more information should be given. Here are a few to start:

1. The query itself
2. The underlying structure of the tables including existing indexes
3. Execution plan

As many of the comments have mentioned already, and from what I can guess from the limited information provided, here are a few things to look at:

**What is the percentage of NULL values in the person_key column?**

- If it is very less, then a rowstore nonclustered index on that column
  should be able to cover your that search. All the selected columns in the query can be included under INCLUDE clause of this index.
  Related MVP link to get some insight: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/are-nulls-stored-in-a-nonclustered-index/
- If the percentage is more, here are a few options that can help:

  - Create a filtered nonclustered rowstore index on person_key with WHERE person_key IS NULL clause in it. Filtered index will reduce the size of the index to search on and will get you a much better performance. All the selected columns in the query can be included under INCLUDE clause of this index.
  - Create a nonclustered columnstore index on the table which covers the columns used in the query. Columnstore index compresses the data by storing one value of a column once where possible, reducing the searchable data size and hence significantly enhances the SELECT query performance. If any column has low cardinality, the performance enhancement by use of a columnstore index on such columns is drastic. You can also make this index filtered.
  - You can think about making the column a SPARSE column (provided you know the limitations of a SPARSE column). Sparse columns handle NULL values extremely efficiently.
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Please remember that you need to always look at what columns you are selecting. If you are doing a SELECT * or have columns in SELECT which are not covered by your index, that means even if you are being able to leverage an index to cover the searching on person_key column, but to fetch the values of the remaining column it has to go look at the existing clustered index or fetch the data from HEAP by scanning all the leaf pages. That will not make the query any fast.