# TSQL multiple joins vs multiple requests from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core application using Dapper to connect to the database. In one of my business classes I have to get some pretty big set of data from 4 tables. What's better solution for that?

1. Creating select with 4 inner joins.
2. Creating basic select without inner joins, and then foreach that collection in C# and invoke another selects to get data from next tables etc.

It's basically choice between one request to Database which will select lots of data or multiple requests to database for multiple smaller parts of data.

Comment: *Better* is what aspect? The join solution should probably be the fastest one. You should [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few reasons why I think Join should work better:

1. As long as you are applying the proper filter conditions in your SQL
   query, you will be fetching only the required data from database
   into your application layer. On the contrary to that, if you make 4
   separate selects, you might end having to bring lot more data than
   what would be finally required.
2. 1 call to database engine through your odbc/jdbc connection vs 4 separate calls.
3. If you have properly indexed the underlying tables for covering the
   query, a relational engine is the best place to perform joins among
   structured data as they are designed for that purpose.
   Based on the type of data and underlying structure, SQL Server would
   come up with the best way to access the data, join the data whether
   to perform an indexed merge join, or nested loop join or a hash join
   among different datasets at different points of the query, allocating proper RAM for those activities accordingly **VS** you
   trying to have to design and code the underlying SQL Server searching and sorting
   algorithms and storage decisions all by yourself in your application to perform the same task on the fetched results of those 4 separate selects.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to delay one of the inner join? I believe this would optimize query or no? For example I'm filtering rows by columns of one table, and then when I got those rows I want to make inner join to another table with the records I got. I believe if i just make FROM.. WHERE.. INNER JOIN ... etc. the Join will happen before my where clause.

Comment: When you join 2 tables and apply the joining conditions within the join clause and also filter conditions (if any) in where clause for the first table, SQL Server takes all of those into consideration during Execution Plan building phase and tries to play with as minimal data as possible if you tune the underlying structure properly. Remember that the columns you SELECT has a big role as well. So, try to select only the columns you need and those selected columns should be covered by indexes for faster data retrieval.

Comment: What if  I select summary ~~~40 fields from the joined tables, should i make 40 indexes?

Comment: No, you should not make such mistake. To be able to provide proper performance tuning suggestion, you should provide the query, underlying table structure, size of data, Execution Plan at the minimum. In general, I would suggest you to go through books/scholarly articles on how indexes should be created, how to come up with a good index strategy etc. if you feel you have some gap in understanding in this area. For some quick tipe, you can go through a few of my answers in these questions:

Comment: 1> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582008/why-in-query-tag-is-so-costly-in-sql-stored-procedures/56583225#56583225  2> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585071/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-query-for-null-values-in-sql-server/56586858#56586858

Comment: @CSharpBeginner if you feel the answer was helpful in terms of what you were trying to decide, could you please upvote the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answers San, really appreciate your help, finally I see one request with some joins better than multiple request without joins